# how to insert dynamic input box value into table in single column when id will be matched with the input box name extension id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic, sql-update

I have dynamic input box with a different name and i want to insert into template table value column when `$data['f_id']` will be same of   (marks_'.**$data['f_id']**)  input name.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
foreach($sqls as $data) {
    $fact_id[]=$data['temids'];
    echo '<input type="text" style="float:left;" name="marks_'.$data['f_id'].'">'; 
}
<input type='submit' name='markssubmit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
</form>
if(isset($markssubmit)) {
    foreach($fact_id as $facid) {
        $marks="marks_".$facid; // how do i change this field
        echo "UPDATE `template`  set value=".$marks." where tid=".$tmid." and f_id=".$facid ;   
    }
}
```

my input box will be coming name properly. but when i am updating my echo of sql is coming :-

```
UPDATE `hra_templates`  set mark_value=marks_1 where tem_id=9 and f_id=1
```

,
but it should come

```
UPDATE `hra_templates`  set mark_value=10 where tem_id=9 and f_id=1
```

Comment: is there a problem? You don't need backticks on tables/fields that aren't keywords. Recommending looking up how to avoid SQL injection too.

Comment: @danblack I am just finding the way how to fetch the value of input box by name in Php in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

as i see your code what you actually want Do you want to update something 
    or you want to fetch data from database and then creating input box.
    or you have an id of input box and if that id match with your provided id 
    then need to create an input box. 
    Please Clear this.
    This is the basic that is creating the input box dynamically. 
    $data = array(10,20,30,40);

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  echo '<input type="text" name="marks_'.$value.'">'; 
}
```

Comment: my input box will be coming name properly. but when i am updating my echo of sql is coming UPDATE `hra_templates`  set mark_value=marks_1 where tem_id=9 ,but it should come UPDATE `hra_templates`  set mark_value=10 where tem_id=9

Comment: try this:  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $marks="marks_".$value;
  echo "UPDATE `student` set marks_value = $marks";
}

Comment: "marks_".$value this is coming like marks_1 but for value i want $marks_1 @prakash pandey

Comment: yes it is see this output: UPDATE `student` set marks_value = marks_10

Comment: @TaniyaChowdhury nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
foreach($sqls as $data) {
    $fact_id[]=$data['temids'];
    echo '<input type="text" style="float:left;" name="marks[]">'; 
}
<input type='submit' name='markssubmit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
</form>
if(isset($markssubmit)) {
    foreach($fact_id as $facid) {
        $sql= "UPDATE `template`  set value=".$marks[$facid-1]." where tid=".$tmid." and f_id=".$facid ;   
    }
}
```